# Read Int from hex array

Tags: c++

I have an input array with hex values,

```
const unsigned char arr[]={0x20, 0x34, 0x30};
```

I need to concatenate the values `arr[1]---> 0x34 ---> 4` and 
                          `arr[2]---> 0x30 ---> 0`

to an integer variable like,

```
int val = 40;
```

How can I do this efficiently in c++?.

Comment: `int val = arr[1];`, for example.

Comment: so NUL-terminate your string and use `std::strtol()`.

Comment: `int val = atoi( (char *)&arr[1]);` seems working...

Comment: No, that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  Actuality my array is very large and it ends like 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

Answer (score 1):

As The Paramagnetic Croissant commented, you can turn the array to a string (null terminated at the very least) and use strtol

Example:

```
const unsigned char arr[]={0x20, 0x34, 0x30};
string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(arr), 3);
int val = strtol(s.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
```

Comment: except that this fails to NUL-terminate the string.

Comment: It does, the conversation to std::string (and use of c_str function) takes care of that. The code runs and works as expected. You can claim it isn't the most efficient code, but it's simple and effective.

Comment: Actually my array is very large and I need to extract data to integer from many place according to index.

Comment: @Haris, that's a different question all together. The method here remains valid but only part of the solution to your overall problem, obviously you have to have a way to identify the sub-arrays which would make each number, once you have that (by length, or by null-termination, or whatever) then you can use strtol to turn that sub-array to an integer. Going through std::string in case you don't have a null-terminated char sequence is a convenience (which can also help converting just sub-arrays, by constructor of pointer and length).

Comment: @Eran No, the conversion to `std::string` from `const char *` calls the `string(const char *, Allocator)` overload of the constructor which expects a NUL-terminated C string (which `arr` is not). Hence, your code invokes undefined behavior. You either need to provide an explicit length or use two pointers (iterators), one to the beginning to the array and one to the one-past-end element. Furthermore, if you are converting to `std::string` anyway, it's better to use `std::stoi()` or `std::stol()` for the conversion (or just use `strtol` and there's no need for `std::string` at all.)

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant, c_str() guarantees null-termination, but for stricter code, changed to constructor with length.

Comment: @Eran **I know that `c_str()` guarantees NUL-termination.** I was **not** talking about `c_str()`. I was talking about the constructor. You don't seem to get my point.